# getElementById using substring of the id: Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using ADAL for authenticating user for using my Angular 4 application. By when I use the following method from Adal.js:

```
acquireToken // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.authenticationcontext.acquiretoken.aspx
```

it creates an `iFrame` that I would like to delete once the token is acquired. But, the `id` of that iFrame is dynamic, it starts with something like: "adalRenewFrame...." and then the token (which is just a string of characters). So is there a way to get that element by using substring "adalRenewFrame"?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you can get `id` of iFrame. You can use [startsWith()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_startswith.asp) function of Javascript. Below is working example:

```js
var id = "adalRenewFrame23219874033";
var fixWord = "adalRenewFrame";

if (id.startsWith(fixWord)) {
  console.log("true"); // will return true
  // you code to remove iFrame here
} else {
  console.log("false")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is simple. Use `document.querySelector` API with a CSS attribute based selector.

```
function deleteIFrame() {
    // It selects iframe whose id contains adalRenewFrame
    const iFrame = document.querySelector(`iframe[id*='adalRenewFrame']`)
    if (iFrame) {
        iFrame.parent.removeChild(iFrame);
    }
}
```

Of you can also use attribute starting with selector like `document.querySelector("iframe[id^='adalRenewFrame']")`.

Additionally, if you know some parent element by its ID or CLASS, you can use it to scope your query search.

[Refer to MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) for more available selectors.